# New column based in multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
     a    b
0  100   90
1   30  117
2   90   99
3  200   94
```

I want to create a new `df["c"]` with next conditions:

- If `a > 50` and b is into `(a ± 0.5a)`, then `c = a`
- If `a > 50` and b is out `(a ± 0.5a)`, then `c = b`
- If `a <= 50`, then `*c = a*`

Output should be:

```
     a    b    c
0  100   90  100
1   30  117   30
2   90   99   90
3  200   94   94
```

I´ve tried:

```
df['c'] = np.where(df.eval("0.5 * a <= b <= 1.5 * a"), df.a, df.b)
```

But I don´t know how to include the last condition `(If a <= 50, then c = a)` in this sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you'll just need to add an `or` clause inside your eval string.

```
np.where(df.eval("(0.5 * a <= b <= 1.5 * a) or (a <= 50)"), df.a, df.b)
#                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
array([100,  30,  90,  94])
```